# Optimize very large amount of moving 2D objects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

The problem - lack of optimization.
I have the image on input,and big amount of square sprites on output,that moves to their destinated positions.
Is there a way to make it more performanced? I don't have any problems with CPU or GPU load,no matter image size. I want to make pixel by pixel movement,without making pixel clasters.

That's a test for 125x143 pixels

[image]

That's a test for 249x295 pixels

[image]

That's a test for 768x768 pixels (start fps was 6 and after movement - 8)

[image]

That's a test for 384x384 pixels (no transparent)

[image]

About code - that's script that creates all sprite and gives them color:

```
using UnityEngine;


public class CreateImage : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject _prefab;
    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D _image;

    private Color[] _pixels;


    private void Start()
    {
        _pixels = _image.GetPixels();

        for (int i = 0; i < _image.width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _image.height; j++)
            {
                var color = _pixels[i + _image.width * j];

                if (color.a == 0)
                    continue;

                var pixel = Instantiate(_prefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity, transform).transform;
                pixel.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = color;
                pixel.GetComponent<PixelMovement>().SetPosition(new Vector2(i*pixel.localScale.x, j*pixel.localScale.y));
            }

        _pixels = null;
    }
}
```

Movement of sprite in this script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PixelMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _speed;

    private Vector3 _estimatedPosition;

    public void SetPosition(Vector2 position) => _estimatedPosition = position;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (transform.localPosition == _estimatedPosition)
            Destroy(transform.GetComponent<PixelMovement>());

        transform.localPosition = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, _estimatedPosition, _speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

After sprite gets to it's destination,script deletes.That make a little improve but problem still remains.On my prefab i have only script that moves it,and sprite renderer.

May be using UI images instead of sprites would be better? (I don't have any reasons for making this,just want to get some knowledge about way to optimize big amount of objects)

Comment: Making it UI would definitely be slower. I'm curious what the profiler says, is it the script that's slow or just the amount of objects it's trying to render? Btw you could cache/serialize the components for the pixel prefab.

Comment: Well,if the scripts are deleted,fps still remains slow.(Like 8 for image with crow).Looking to profiler - on startup script update take from 130ms to 200ms,but when image done it's 0(because all instances are deleted). Problem in Camera.Render it's always take something like 140ms. So from start i have delay 400ms and in end 160ms.

Comment: Later i will try to make some "laggy" script and compare performance. But the problem remains in Unity,that can't render this big amount of objects.

Comment: I guess you could look at the frame debugger to see if they're batching well or not. Also if you're not using URP, that could give you a little boost.

Comment: Well it drawing it like column by column and take 28 instances every frame. I will try URP and tell the results.

Comment: So,script is laggy,it's dropping fps to 3-5 (defines from image size) and then it grows to normal values ,but if camera starts render the objects - fps stays at point 7.0~3. Even after script is done it's work. So is there path to overcome this (URP doesn't help).

Comment: `GameObject`s are not really meant for this kind of thing. Just the overhead you get from using `GameObject`s for this is more than 99% of the performance issues. I would suggest: Try the same thing with `Entity`(ies) in ECS, try to set actual pixels in some `Texture2D` instead of moving `GameObject`s, and perhaps using a particle system could work too.

Comment: Particles system really improves the speed,fps growed for 2 to even 10 times,but still - from 2 to 4 not so big difference. I will try the ECS,and say the results.

Comment: And i can generate image only with one color,because of startColor property.

Comment: It seems to me like something that’d be better handled with a shader, though I wouldn’t know how personally. To be honest, though, in the gifs at least there’s not a lot to differentiate the effect from just an expanding circular mask revealing a static image — only the colour of the edge row of pixels which is pretty subtle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the most optimized way at this moment - Particle System.
Somehow using outdated methods i was able to emit particles with different colors. For low resolution (125x143) it went up from 60 fps (when script is running),and 120fps (when camera just renders objects),to stable 280-300 fps.
As for our new participant - 649x949: when particles moving fps somewhat at 6-7,and when movement ended it remains at 11-12. Amount of particles - 615901. I not familliar with Unity Particle System,so there still things that can make it run faster,i think.

[image]

And Crow the Destroyer runs at 28-40 fps,so this is really big improvement.

[image]

I moving particles through generation script:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using static UnityEngine.ParticleSystem;

public class CreateImageParticles : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private ParticleSystem _system; //particle system
    [SerializeField]
    private Texture2D _image; //image texture

    private Color[] _pixels; //array for saving colors from image
    private List<Color> _colors; //colors for particles
    private List<Vector3> _positions;//destinted positions of particle

    private void Start()
    {
        _pixels = _image.GetPixels();
        _colors = new List<Color>();
        _positions = new List<Vector3>();

        for (int i = 0; i < _image.width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < _image.height; j++)
            {
                var color = _pixels[i + _image.width * j]; //saving colors for image 

                if (color.a == 0) //is pixel are transparent - skip it
                    continue;

                _colors.Add(color);
                _positions.Add(new Vector3(i, j));
            }

        _system.maxParticles = _positions.Count; //seting max particles count
        //emmiting particles with different colors
        if (_system.maxParticles != _system.particleCount)
            for (int i = 0; i < _system.maxParticles; i++)
                _system.Emit(Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero, _system.startSize, 9999, _colors[i]);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        Particle[] particles = new Particle[_system.maxParticles];
        _system.GetParticles(particles);//saving current particles to our created array
        for (int i = 0; i < particles.Length; i++)
        {
            if (particles[i].position == _positions[i]) //check is particle already at destinated position
                continue;
            particles[i].position = Vector3.MoveTowards(particles[i].position, _positions[i], 20 * Time.deltaTime); // moving particle
        }
        _system.SetParticles(particles); //set particles back to emmiter 
    }
}
```

That's what a profiler says about crow:

[image]

And for big image:

[image]

So next time i will try the ECS,and compare performance.
Thanks to Iggy and Petrusion for help.